# Change opacity of text from 0 to 1 with popup like effect

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I want to create a simple text animation like freepik.com When we hover over any image in freepik its title changes its opacity from 0 to 1 with a sort of like a popup. Just checkout this transition at [Freepik.com](http://freepik.com) There are some images on front page hover over them and you see the text view like some popup. I just want to create this transition and nothing else. Help me Thanks.

Comment: That is overlay.Check this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp

Comment: I do not want just an overlay. I already created the overlay. If you visit freepik.com. When you hover over an image it is not just animating from 0 to 1. It looks like it emerges from the center. I want to create this effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how **freepik.com** is doing it:

## Pop Out

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0);
-moz-transform: scale(0);
-ms-transform: scale(0);
-o-transform: scale(0);
transform: scale(0);
```

### to on `:hover`

```
webkit-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
-o-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
```

---

## Opacity

```
opacity: 0;
```

### to on `:hover`

```
opacity: 1;
```

---

## Animate

```
-webkit-transition: 250ms ease;
-moz-transition: 250ms ease;
-o-transition: 250ms ease;
transition: 250ms ease;
```

Apply to all elements that you want to animate, but make sure it's not applied to just the `:hover` state.

---

You can see the code from their site in the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of code]

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

I have written an example for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0a6rn5qh/2/)

The way it works is it uses the `transition: transform 1s;` to make it transition slowly and smoothly and it uses `transform: rotateY(90deg);` to have it start hidden by having it turned at right angle making it virtually flat and then `transform: rotateY(0deg);` inside of the `.popout-div:hover p`, which gets when you're hovering over the div and selects all `p` elements inside it, to have it reappear in a popout way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this - transition opacity and scale on hover.

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.details{
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, .5);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scale(0.3,0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.container:hover .details{
  transform: scale(1,1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="http://adrianweb.net/includes/images/service-webdev.jpg" />
  
<div class="details">
Details going up  
</div>
</div>
```

But Freepik.com maybe have to separate column one going from center to left and other from center to right.